# Should I unlock if I call another function inside of a function?

Tags: c++, mutex

Let's say I have a simple code like this

```
functionA(){
     lock(lockA);

     //doing something with a shared data;
     functionB();
     unLock(lockA);
}

functionB(){
     lock(lockB);
     //doting something with another shared data
     unLock(lockB);
}
```

I was wondering if I should unlock before I call functionB or it doesn't matter. Also if I have 2 shared data(A and B) then should I have two mutex lock variables? or can I just use one? Thanks in advance..

Comment: A [lock hierarchy](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/204801163) can be used to ensure that you do not deadlock.  You must [Avoid Calling Unknown Code While Inside a Critical Section](http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/202802983) (e.g., when holding a lock).  You must also ensure that the system state is consistent before unlocking and you must ensure that it is safe to reacquire the lock and resume after calling the external code (e.g., remember that someone else may have changed the shared state while you did not hold the lock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If A and B are absolutely not correlated and you won't do anything else with A after you call function B you should unlock first. There is no need to keep the mutex if you are not going to access A any more.

You should be careful of deadlocks though if you use two lock and do not always obtain them in the same order. Like if you follow your unmodified example locks are acquired on A-B order. If there is a case in your program such that you will acquire locks in B-A order it may cause a deadlock.

You can just use two different locks or a single one depending on the level of granularity you  need. Do you mind functions working on A blocks all other functions working on B as well. If that is acceptable for you single lock would be much easier to manage.

Comment: Can I just take lock/unlock out from functionB since functionA has lock/unlock?

Comment: If you decided to use just a single lock you can definitely remove the lock/unlock from function b. But make, sure if another function also calls function B it also has to acquire *the* lock before calling function B.

Comment: In my case, functionA is the only place where calls function B..So I guess I can take lock/unlock out from functionB. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With current design you could face a deadlock - if some other thread had `lockB` locked and tries to acquire a lock to `lockA` both threads are trapped. On the other hand releasing lock to `lockA` could allow undesired concurrent access to the shared data.

So you have to assess the needs of your program. If you want two threads to access several variables at once (like consistently modify those variables) you should have one lock for all those variables and hold the lock until you've finished access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `functionB()` isn't called from anywhere else, it's safe enough to use just one lock.

Even if you need to use two locks, make sure you release them as soon the work on the shared variable they lock will no longer be used.

With the scenario you have, you may end up into a dead lock if `functionB()` itself attempted to put a lock on A. Therefore, it's good practice to release locks prior to calling functions that may in turn try to establish a lock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't get that part "functionB() itself attempted to put a lock on A". From the code, functionB only tries put a lock on B..Could you please give me an example in what case functionB might act as that way? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I know it doesn't put a lock on A, but I was trying to mention that if you had to modify your code or some external function which may also put locks. You would end up with dead locks as described by Szere Dyeri.